Solution of boundary value problem .
Let $y$ represent the solution of the boundary value problem:
$$ (xy')' - 2y' + \frac{y}{x} = 1, \quad y(1) = 0, \quad y(e^4) = 4e^4. $$
How can it be shown that $y(e) = -\frac{e}{2}$ in a very short amount of time?
This is a multiple-choice question with 4 possible answers, and the correct one is $-\frac{e}{2}$. The problem is meant to be solved in around 3 minutes during the exam. While one approach involves solving the equation in its entirety—by converting it into standard form, finding the general solution to the homogeneous equation as $y = cx + d \log x$. Now  applying the method of variation of parameters and then applying boundary conditions to determine arbitrary constants and subsequently calculating $y(e)$, but this process is  lengthy. Please provide a shortcut or faster method to obtain the result.

@whpowell96 of then I will edit it .

@whpowell96 If possible provide some solution. Thank you .

@whpowell96 I edit the question .

$$(xy′)′−2y′+\frac{y}{x}=1$$
$$y'' - \frac{y'}{x} + \frac{y}{x^{2}} = \frac{1}{x}$$
$$(y' - \frac{y}{x})' = \frac{1}{x}$$
$$(y' - \frac{y}{x}) = \log (x) + C_{1}$$
$$\frac{1}{x}(y' - \frac{y}{x}) = \frac{\log (x)}{x} + \frac{C_{1}}{x} = (\frac{y}{x})'$$
$$ \frac{y}{x} = \frac{(\log x)^{2}}{2} + C_{1}(\log x) + C_{2}$$
$$y(1) = 0 \implies C_{2} = 0 , \quad y(e^{4}) = 4e^{4} \implies C_{1} = -1 $$
$$y(e) = \frac{e}{2} - e = -\frac{e}{2}$$

Thank you.......
